# An exercise question in Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or give a counterexample: if $U_1$, $U_2$, $W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $V$ = $U_1\oplus W$   and  $V = U_2 \oplus W$, then $U_1 = U_2$.

I'm a beginner in linear algebra and I'm frustrated at these types of questions, could you please offer an example solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. I have just finished chapter one. I actually finished the first two chapters in Hoffman's Linear Algebra but unfortunately it is harder than I had anticipated so I switched to Alxer's.

Comment: ok anyway it was a bad idea. By the way, Axler's book is great in my opinion

Comment: I tend to like the book, but the exercises seem to be way too complicated compared to the material he teaches in each chapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F$ be your base field, $V=F^2$, $U_1=\langle (1,0)\rangle$, $U_2=\langle (1,1)\rangle$, $W=\langle (0,1)\rangle$ and check the properties.

Comment: Comment for OP: $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_n\rangle = \operatorname{span}({v_1,\ldots,v_n})$ (the later notation is used in Axler's book).